# Split file into separate files using pattern

Tags: text-processing

I need to split a file (see sample) into separate files. Each new file shall inherit the name in line 7 i.e. `SAMPLE1.txt`, `SAMPLE2.txt` etc.

```
@File_Version: 4
@Coordinate_Type_is: 1
@Export_Type_is: 1
@Number_of_P: 1
@T_Type_Name: , 
#File_Version____________-> 4
#Name____________-> SAMPLE1
#Type____________-> 3

#End_of_file_header
    000000.00000    0000000.00000   0000.00000
    000000.00000    0000000.00000   0000.00000
...
EOD

@File_Version: 4
@Coordinate_Type_is: 1
@Export_Type_is: 1
@Number_of_P: 1
@T_Type_Name: , 
#File_Version____________-> 4
#Name____________-> SAMPLE2
#Type____________-> 3

#End_of_file_header
    000000.00000    0000000.00000   0000.00000
    000000.00000    0000000.00000   0000.00000
...
EOD

@File_Version: 4
@Coordinate_Type_is: 1
@Export_Type_is: 1
@Number_of_P: 1
@T_Type_Name: , 
#File_Version____________-> 4
#Name____________-> SAMPLE3
#Type____________-> 3

#End_of_file_header
    000000.00000    0000000.00000   0000.00000
    000000.00000    0000000.00000   0000.00000
...
EOD
```

Comment: thanks. it was not obvious where I can edit the format.

Comment: See [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with `awk`:

```
awk '{
        if(/@File_Version:/){k=$0;}
        else{k=k"\n"$0}
     } 
    /^#Name/{n=$2}
    /EOD/{
        print k > n".txt"; 
    }' file
```

#### Explanation

- `if(/^@File_Version:/){k=$0;}` : if this line starts with `@File_Version:`, save the line as `k`.
- `else{k=k"\n"$0}` : for all other lines, add a newline (`\n`) followed by the current line to the current value of `k`.
- `/^#Name/{n=$2}` : if this line starts with `#Name`, set the variable `n` to the second field (the name).
- `/^EOD/{print k > n".txt";}` : if this line starts with `EOD`, print the variable `k` (which now contains the entire record) into a file called `n.txt` where `n` is the name saved in the previous step.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/#Name/{ x=$NF;  }; /#End_of_file_header/,/EOD/{ print > x} '  test1
```

If line start by `#name`, `x` store the last word of the line. 
Then for all block delimited by `#End_of_file_header` and `EOD` i print the lines into a file which name is content of `x`

This one will skip the file header to only store data into the file.